# All necessary commands for Using Magento 2 - For beginner

Tags: magento2, command-line, git

**ALL Basic Commands**
I am new in Magento 2 but require I necessary commands including bash commands and git command to working with Linux based system ,

Comment: Please go through this - https://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/magento-2-useful-commands-list-391 . Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Magento Commands**

```
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php  bin/magento module:enable IWD_Opc 

/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php bin/magento module:status



cat bin/empty_json > /var/www/vhosts/u21132485.onlinehome-server.com/magentotest.u21132485.onlinehome-server.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/js-translation.json

cat bin/empty_json > /var/www/vhosts/u21132485.onlinehome-server.com/magentotest.u21132485.onlinehome-server.com/pub/static/frontend/Sm/market/en_US/js-translation.json


 /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php  bin/magento cache:flush
 /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php  bin/magento cache:clean

 /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade


 /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php -d memory_limit=2000M bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

 /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php bin/magento set:upg

 /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php -d memory_limit=2000M bin/magento indexer:reindex

 /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php  deploy:mode:set developer
```

**git commands**

```
git pull origin beta0.2

git add -A stages all changes

git add . stages new files and modifications, without deletions

git add -u stages modifications and deletions, without new files

git commit -m "discard changes"

git log

git checkout 7e7eaf42a8bb07855b6f2f242f62ff944560eb50

git log --oneline --graph --color --all --decorate

git checkout 76fc7e8a

git checkout -b beta0.2 76fc7e8a
```

**Bash commands**

```
Shows the last 10 lines from an error log. 
tail -n 10 -f var/log/system.log
tail -n 10 -f error.log
tail -f error.log
chmod -R 777 /www/store
mv foldername/ ../ 

If you are going for a console command it would be: chmod -R 777 /www/store. The -R (or --recursive) options makes it recursive.

You can also use mv to move a whole directory and its content:

/pub/media/catalog/product/placeholder/default/

tar -xzf pubbkp.tar.gz

//show all hidden file in a directory
ls -ld .?* 


zip -r backup.zip * -x "backup_old/*" "old/ignoreDir2/*"

mv includes/* ./`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento module:status
php bin/magento module:enable Algolia_AlgoliaSearch
php bin/magento module:disable Algolia_AlgoliaSearch

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy


php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento deploy:mode:show
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento cache:clean

php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento indexer:reindex
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento cache:flush
php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento cache:clean

php -dmemory_limit=5G bin/magento module:status
```

Answer (score 0):

for people who approach for the first time with magento I always recommend:
https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2

Here is a command manager who in addition to explaining what he does, adds a list of very useful commands such as the fast database dump which is much much much faster than the magento 2 backup

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

- rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml ;
- rm -rf var/di/ *var/generation/* var/cache/ *var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/ *var/composer_home/cache/*
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento indexer:reindex
- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento cache:flush
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
- chmod -R 777 var pub generated

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please add details with each command then it'll make sense for beginner.